# Encryption truncated

Tags: java, encryption

I have an encryption function that has always worked well in various environments, but lately, it's been coughing up strange results.

Here's the code:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(String pstrInput) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream ms;
    CipherOutputStream encStream;
    OutputStreamWriter sw;
    byte[] buffer;

    ms = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    encStream = new CipherOutputStream(ms, getEncCipher());
    sw = new OutputStreamWriter(encStream);

    try {
        sw.write(pstrInput);
        sw.write("\r\n");
        sw.close();
        encStream.close();
        ms.close();
        buffer = ms.toByteArray();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected IO errors in Security Encrypt", e);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

The problem is that, in some environments, `buffer` will be truncated to 8 bytes, and I have no idea why.

I can reproduce the problem on my machine by commenting out the `encStream.close()` line, but I also have no idea why.

To the best of my knowledge, the machines in question (dev and QA) are running the same JVM (OpenJDK 1.7 64-bit). The only difference is that the dev machine is running the code inside Eclipse's Jetty and QA is running a Tomcat, but that shouldn't make any difference...

Any pointers?

Comment: `0x3A28213A`
`0x6339392C`
`0x7363682E`

Comment: Why don't you close the streams and writer in the finally block?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Best practices are nice and all, but I have to close the cipher stream where I do, or it truncates. Truncating is the behavior I'm trying to understand and eliminate. Closing in the finally block doesn't work.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/138/

Comment: @SLaks tnx. OP: ok, ok, just trying to help

Comment: @AdriaanKoster Turns out you were very close to the source of the problem. See the accepted answer. +1

Comment: I won't add a smug comment about best practices here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not truncated output. The problem is garbage added to the output on the machines where the code "works". The truncated version is actually the correct one.

Closing the stream writer closes the underlying stream. Additionally, closing a closed stream is not supposed to have any effect.

However, there seems to be a bug with some versions of CipherStream, whereby closing it again actually causes it to flush and encrypt a new block.

That's why commenting out the encStream.close() "recreates" the problem (by actually fixing it).

Comment: From the CipherStream specs, it's not obvious which is the correct behavior. In any case, the second `close` in my code is indeed a bug. Thanks.